# Python matplot Y axis scaled by scientific float number

Tags: python, matplotlib

I just run into this problem. When I try to plot a list of values range from 100 to 120, the y axis instead of being scaled from 100 to 120, it is showing 1.09+e4 on top where each step is scaled to 0.02.

I am wondering if anyone has the same problem and could help me out with this?

Thanks!

Comment: Please can you show us the values you're plotting? It would be much easier to help if we can see the code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Additionally, please show a bit of the code that you use to plot, specifically the lines regarding the y axis.